# Clicking on label does not check the associated checkbox

Tags: jquery, jqtransform

I've been strugling with a bug that impact jQtransform :

When you click on a label associated to a checkbox, it "visually" checks the box but when submitting the form, **it's not sent**. *(so it only checks the jqTransform layer and not the real checkbox)*

- Given the same scenario with a radio -> **it works**
- Clicking direclty on the checkbox -> **it works**

  ```
  $.fn.jqTransCheckBox = function(){
  return this.each(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('jqTransformHidden')) {return;}

      var $input = $(this);
      var inputSelf = this;

      //set the click on the label
      oLabel = jqTransformGetLabel($input);
      oLabel && oLabel.click(function(){aLink.trigger('click');}); // -> Bug here ?

      var aLink = $('<a href="#" class="jqTransformCheckbox"></a>');
      //wrap and add the link
      $input.addClass('jqTransformHidden').wrap('<span class="jqTransformCheckboxWrapper"></span>').parent().prepend(aLink);
      //on change, change the class of the link
                  $input.change(function(){
                    inputSelf.checked && aLink.addClass('jqTransformChecked') || aLink.removeClass('jqTransformChecked');
                    return true;
                  });
      // Click Handler, trigger the click and change event on the input
      aLink.click(function(){
          //do nothing if the original input is disabled
          if($input.attr('disabled')){return false;}
          //trigger the envents on the input object
                          $(this).toggleClass('jqTransformChecked');
          $input.trigger('click').trigger("change");
          return false;
      });

      // set the default state
      this.checked && aLink.addClass('jqTransformChecked');
  });
  ```

  };

Thanks

Comment: not really because I want to find the solution, if you have a clue you're welcome ;-)

Comment: For those not using jQuery.. I had this problem (label not checking checkbox) in my Angular 2 app. Removing the `for` attribute helped as the browser was clicking the checkbox **twice**, for god knows what reason. Thanks to @Petar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `aLink.trigger('click')` call isn't working for some reason.
I fixed this by replacing this line:

```
oLabel && oLabel.click(function(){aLink.trigger('click');});
```

with the following:

```
oLabel && oLabel.click(function(){
    var forAttr = null;
    if(forAttr = $(this).attr('for')) {
        var element = $(this).siblings('#' + forAttr);
        if(element.length) {
            element.trigger('click');
        }
    }
    else {
        aLink.trigger('click');
    }
});
```

What this does is check in the label's siblings for the element in its "for" attribute and if the element exists it uses that, instead of aLink.
I'm using siblings because it's faster than searching the entire document. Feel free to change that if needed.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
Okay, i may have rushed into it with this answer. My solution is wrong on many levels.

What i believe is actually happening is that clicking the label causes a double click. So, when clicking the label, the default click is triggered which checks the element and another click is triggered immediately after that which unchecks the checkbox.

My previous solution wasn't actually doing anything, just preventing a second call since none of the conditions actually came through (the '#' + forAttr element isn't a sibling).

I found that just commenting out the line with the error fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

what i've discovered is this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sexi" id="test" />
<label>Female</label>
```

works, but this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sexi" id="test" />
<label for="test">Female</label>
```

doesn't

both works for radio input!

the reason first approach works is actually because in case of checkbox, when you click the label click is fired twice

i'm trying to fix the bug in the code but same code is used for radio and checkbox...hmm..

Comment: You rock! I got here searching for Angular 2/Bootstrap 4 problem almost exactly 5 years later and your answer saved my ass ;)

Comment: @kub1x Glad I could help! Who would expect this would still be an issue in 2017 :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's the same issue, but when radio buttons are transformed, clicking on their labels would let them all checked, although the posted value was correct.

It seems to me that the problem is with jqTransformGetLabel.

It tries to get the label with next() and, if that doesn't work, with prev(). That travels only one level in the DOM. Changing

```
var oLabel = objfield.next();
```

to

```
var oLabel = $(objfield.find('label').get(0));
```

and

```
oLabel = objfield.prev();
```

to

```
oLabel = $(objfield.parents('label').get(0));
```

inside jqTransformGetLabel seemed to solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Vlad Cazacu mentioned the problem is caused by double click (default one and the one called in click function).

To avoid default event we have to return false:

```
oLabel && oLabel.click(function () { aLink.trigger('click'); return false; });
```

at least it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly my case, but i found this page trying to find a solution to the same problem (fields isn't sent); The difference is that i'm using jQtransform without label, just to identify what rows in a table had checked.

I'm posting this solution just to help someone who arrived here like me, looking for some good tips  ;)

I changed the line 140 (in the original file) like kbalcerek did:

```
oLabel && oLabel.click(function(){aLink.trigger('click'); return false;});
```

Then, inside input.change event (line 147) i changed this...

```
this.checked && aLink.addClass('jqTransformChecked') || aLink.removeClass('jqTransformChecked');
```

... Into this:

```
$(this).attr('checked') && aLink.addClass('jqTransformChecked') || !$(this).attr('checked') && aLink.removeClass('jqTransformChecked');
```

And finally, inside aLink.click event (line 155) i had to modify this...

```
$input.trigger('click').trigger("change");
```

... Into that:

```
$input.attr('checked', !$input.attr('checked')).trigger("change");
```

In the last two changes my inspiration cames from the Frédéric Hamidi answer for the question "Toggle Checkboxes on/off".

Solved for me =) Hope to help someone